# tomcat6 caching issue

Tags: caching, tomcat6

When I access http://www.my_url.com/index.jsp I get the updated web page, but when I'm trying to access http://www.my_url.com I get avery old version of the page.

In the localhost_access_log I see:

```
[17/Nov/2011:08:25:11 +0000] "GET /index.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 27487
[17/Nov/2011:08:25:11 +0000] "GET /js/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
:
:
[17/Nov/2011:08:26:32 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 -
[17/Nov/2011:08:26:32 +0000] "GET /js/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

The system is Tomcat6 on centos server. I set the jsp file: `response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");` and deleted the `/var/cache/tomcat6` folder

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I use to prevent caching

```
// This will prevent catching of the results
            response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
```

Comment: Thanks, tried it, didn't help. Only after I pointed the welcome page to different age and then returned  I got updated page.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing help but only after I pointed the welcome page to different age and then returned I got updated page